# show "continued" for nested description list item on page break

Tags: lists, page-breaking, enumitem, description

I'm using enumitem to create a description list.

These lists can sometimes be nested and can get very long. 
When a list item with a lot of description text breaks over a page it is difficult to tell to which item the current description belongs.

In these cases, I would like to put a note at the top of the page that shows the preceding item name, "continued".

Here is a MWE. I have put in the textsuperscript text manually; what I would like to do is make that
happen automatically any time the list goes over a pagebreak.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{Options}{description}{5}
\setlist[Options]{topsep=0.25em plus 0.2em minus 0.1em,
        parsep=0.5\baselineskip plus .1\baselineskip minus .1\baselineskip,
        itemsep=0.25em plus 0.2em minus 0.1em,
        partopsep=0pt,
}
\newcommand*{\Option}[1]{%
    \item[#1]\mbox{}\newline%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{Options}
    \Option{first item} and explanatory text
    \Option{second item} and more text%
        \clearpage\textsuperscript{second item \emph{continued}}\newline%
        more text describing the second item.
    \end{Options}

\end{document}
```

Here is another case using nested options:

```
\begin{Options}
    \Option{first item} and explanatory text
    \Option{second item} and more text%
        \begin{Options}
            \Option{nested option} text
        \end{Options}

    text that belongs to \emph{second item}\clearpage
    more text about \emph{second item}

\end{Options}
```

Comment: Should the note be part of the text?  If so, should it be formatted like an `\item` from the list?  Or, should the note be presented in the header or footer of the document?

Comment: Thats a good question. I think it would be more natural looking if the note starts the text block, possibly in a different font or gray color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using the [atbegshi](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi) package, together with an `\if...` statement where you set the `\if...` equal to true at the start of the option and then to false at the end using `\setlist`.

Here's a MWE. I have used the same continuation message that you used above.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{atbegshi}

\newif\ifInOptions\InOptionsfalse
\newlist{Options}{description}{5}
\setlist[Options]{topsep=0.25em plus 0.2em minus 0.1em,
        parsep=0.5\baselineskip plus .1\baselineskip minus .1\baselineskip,
        itemsep=0.25em plus 0.2em minus 0.1em,
        partopsep=0pt,before=\InOptionstrue,after=\InOptionsfalse,
}
\let\lastOption\relax
\newcommand*{\Option}[1]{\def\lastOption{#1}% remember the option for continued...
    \item[#1]\mbox{}\newline%
}
\AtBeginShipout{\ifInOptions%
  \AtBeginShipoutNext{\textsuperscript{\lastOption \emph{continued}}\newline}%
\fi}

\begin{document}
  \begin{Options}
    \Option{first item} and explanatory text
    \Option{second item} and more text%
        \clearpage%\textsuperscript{second item \emph{continued}}\newline%
        more text describing the second item.
  \end{Options}
\end{document}
```

This even seems to play well with nested environments because the `\ifInOptions` is implicitly set within `\begin{group}...\end{group}`.

Comment: However, with nested options, when the parent option continues after the nested list and a page-break occurs, the text still refers to the nested option. I'll edit the original question with an example.

Comment: @TimA Funny, there seemed to be a very complimentary comment here yesterday:) I don't have time to play with this now but I suspect that my `\gdef` is over zealous and that changing this is to a `\def` will fix the problem. Have just edited the solution so it is clear what I mean and will check to see if it works latter.

Comment: @TimA I just checked and, as I suspected, using `\def` instead of `\gdef` it does remember the correct `\Option` to continue when the options are nested.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew, that does seem to do the job now! really great example with no more code than needed: simplicity. ;-)

Comment: @TimA Yes, the problem with my first attempt was too much code: `\gdef` should have been `\def`, so less is clearly better!